# Como exportar uma tabela específica de um html para outro html via php?

Tags: php, html

Tenho um ficheiro HTML com múltiplas tabelas ao longo do código. A função deste ficheiro é exportar estas mesmas para outros ficheiros HTML (um ficheiro por cada tabela). Portanto este ficheiro funciona como uma espécie de banco de informação onde eu mais tarde se quiser, só tenho de alterar o primeiro ficheiro e não ir à procura de um tal ficheiro especifico para editar a tabela

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso no php? Já experimentei o include e o require envia o html todo, e não só a `<table></table>`, que eu quero.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem essas informações armazenadas no banco de dados? Não seria mais fácil salvar elas no banco e montar o HTML depois? Se isso não for possível, salve esse documento HTML em alguma pasta e depois solicite ele usando o Curl, acredito que assim você consiga incluir o conteúdo dele ao restante da página.